# Redirecting old URL to new URL using htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect my all old Wordpress website url to a new WordPress website. I am able to redirect the main url but my i am not able to redirect the internal pages url. Can you please help. This is what i used to redirect the old url to the new one.

```
Redirect 301 / https://test1.com/subfolder/
```

This one is working fine but i need to redirect https://test.com/subfolder/page1 to https://test1.com/subfolder/page1. Currently this link (https://test.com/subfolder/page1) is also redirecting to the https://test1.com/subfolder/

Comment: entire incoming `request_uri` will be appended to the /subfolder/. Did you mean the `Redirect 301 /subfolder/ https://test1.com/subfolder/`?

Comment: Yes actually the new/old website is on the subfolder and both the websites have same pages i need to change only the url main part i-e test to test1 everything else should remain same

Answer (score 0):

Insert this rule **just below** `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://test1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

# rest of the rules go here
```

You must clear your browser cache before testing this change.